# Multiply numbers that are modulo $M$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let's say  $a$ modulo $M$ is $r_j$. How I can prove that $sa$ modulo $M$ is still $r_j$ and not another integer, where $\gcd(s,M)=1$.

Answer (score 2):

That's false. Using your meaning (where "$\mathrm{mod}$" is interpreted as an operation, not an equivalence relation), we have $6\bmod 5=1$ and $\gcd(2,5)=1$ but $(2\cdot 6)\bmod 5=12\bmod 5= 2$.